# batch file: remove file name in path in a string

Tags: batch-file

I have created a small batch file for windows, and I am having a small issue:

I defined a variable which contains a string, the path of a source file:

> D:\git_repos\ALM_Sandboxs\Sensor_Config\StateManagement\ssm_state.cpp

I ´d like to extract the path without the file name:

> D:\git_repos\ALM_Sandboxs\Sensor_Config\StateManagement\

Since the path can change, and so does the file name, I am having difficulties to do this. There are many ways, but I wasn´t able to use any of them:

The first one would be to count charaters of the file name:

```
set NumberOfCharacter
```

and do

```
set FilePath=%FilePathTemp2:~,%NumberOfCharacter%%
```

But this doesn´t work. I can only use number with this syntax:
    `set FilePath=%FilePathTemp2:~,-18%`  ==> This works, but I´d like to read 18 from a variable

I have read that the batch interpreter can´t resolve the % pairs, so I tried

```
for /l %%x in (1,1,%strlength%) do set %FilePathTemp2%=%FilePathTemp2:~,-1%
```

It doesn´t work either, because the for loop seems not able to change FilePathTemp2 with a global scope.

I would be thankfull for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%a in (D:\git_repos\ALM_Sandboxs\Sensor_Config\StateManagement\ssm_state.cpp) do echo %%~dpa
```

(this is batch file syntax. To use it directly on command line, replace both `%%` with a single `%`)

The usage of modifiers (like `%%~dpa`) and which modifiers are possible is explained in `for /?`

Comment: Hello Stephan,
Thanks for the help! It worked, here is what I am using:  

 `:: remove file name from path (only folders), and go to path<br/>  
 for %%a in (%FilePathTemp2%) do set FilePath=%%~dpa  
 cd %FilePath%`

Comment: @SebastienL You could simply get away without having to set the variable then cd to it. For instance, simply replace `echo` in Stepan's answer with `cd` So you will have `for %%a in (D:\git_repos\ALM_Sandboxs\Sensor_Config\StateManagement\ssm_state.cpp) do cd %%~dpa` you could also use `pushd` especially if you are changing dir to another drive. see `pushd /?` from cmdline for more.